# What datatype to use for Facebook user id in Rails and PostgreSQL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, postgresql, types

I have a PostgreSQL database for a Rails application.

I want to store the Facebook user id so I thought I could use integer but its not big enough so I chose float.

However now Rails adds .0 to the end of my user id's

What datatype can I use so this does not happen for Facebook user ids which are very long `example: 100002496803785`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `:limit => 8` on your integer column to get a `bigint`. For example:

```
class Pancakes < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def change
        create_table :pancakes do |t|
            t.integer :c, :limit => 8
        end
    end
end
```

And then, from `psql`:

```
=> \d pancakes
                         Table "public.pancakes"
 Column |  Type   |                       Modifiers                       
--------+---------+-------------------------------------------------------
 id     | integer | not null default nextval('pancakes_id_seq'::regclass)
 c      | bigint  | not null
Indexes:
    "pancakes_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
```

And there's your [eight byte `bigint`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-numeric.html) column.

You could also use a string for the Facebook ID. You're not doing any arithmetic on the IDs so they're really just opaque bags of bits that happen to look like large integers, strings will sort and compare just fine so they might be the best option. There would be some storage and access overhead due to the increased size of a string over the integer but it probably wouldn't be enough to make any noticeable difference.

Never use a `double` for something that needs to be exact. You'd probably be fine (except for the trailing `.0` of course) in this case because you'd have 52 bits of mantissa and that means that the `double` would act like a 52 bit integer until your values got large enough to require the exponent. Even so, using `double` for this would be an awful idea and an abuse of the type system.

Comment: Thanks for the great tip and I will switch to string.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use postgresql but in mysql I use BIGINT

According to postgresql [data types](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-numeric.html), BIGINT for postgresql as well.

Comment: However rails does not have big int.

Comment: I thought there is bignum or something in rails, no ?

Comment: @chell, postgres has int8, so you do not have problem with postgres, you have problem with rails. Please tag your question properly.

Answer (score 0):

mu is too short has a great answer, I only want to add that if you want to use the ID as a foreign key between tables then you should stick to the BIGINT solution he describes, not use a string.  This is what I use, essentially:

Example:

```
create_table(:photos) do |t|
  t.integer       :fb_uid, :limit => 8 # Facebook ID of the photo record
  t.integer       :facebook_profile_uid, :limit => 8, :null => false # foreign key to user
  # ...
end

create_table(:users) do |t|
  t.integer       :fb_uid, :limit => 8, :null => false # Facebook ID of the user record
  t.integer       :photos_count, :integer, :default => 0
  # ...
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :photos, foreign_key: :facebook_profile_uid, primary_key: :fb_uid
  # ...
end

class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :facebook_profile, foreign_key: :facebook_profile_uid, primary_key: :fb_uid, :counter_cache => true
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Ran into this problem while using the Google uid which also is quite large.

I found the this answer to be most useful:

[Getting error indicating number is "out of range for ActiveRecord::Type::Integer with limit 4" when attempting to save large(ish) integer value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29538530/getting-error-indicating-number-is-out-of-range-for-activerecordtypeinteger)

1. Run a migration to change your table column.
2. Edit the generated migration -> add, limit: 8
3. Run db:migrate to migrate to the database.
4. Restart the rails server.

This will allow you to change the limit of your table column.