# Getting error indicating number is "out of range for ActiveRecord::Type::Integer with limit 4" when attempting to save large(ish) integer value

Tags: ruby, sqlite, activerecord

I'm using SQLite + ActiveRecord in my Ruby app, and here's the error I get while trying to write a big number to the integer field:

> 1428584647765 is out of range for ActiveRecord::Type::Integer with
>   limit 4

But according to the SQLite documentation:

> The value is a signed integer, stored in 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, or 8 bytes depending on the magnitude of the value.

**8 bytes is a plenty of space to store the integer 1428584647765, so why does ActiveRecord give me an error? Why does it think that this is a 4-byte field?**

Comment: The first link on googling “ActiveRecord::Type::Integer with limit” gives [that reference](https://github.com/henrik/rails/commit/1be562db9501007bd82d9385ffc8ca59e23daba9).

Answer (score 53):

I ran into the same problem, and the answer above gave me a clue on how I fixed mine. I propose my answer a little detailed to solving the problem.

You can do this by setting limit on your table column.

**Hack/Steps**

1. Run a migration to change your table column. e.g.

   `rails generate migration change_integer_limit_in_your_table`

   **Note**: `your_table` in the code will be your table name in plural
2. Edit the generated migration such that the generated migration will look like this:

   ```
   class ChangeIntegerLimitInYourTable < ActiveRecord::Migration
      def change
        change_column :your_table, :your_column, :integer, limit: 8
      end 
    end
   ```

   **Note**: The limit of 8 in the code is the storage size which can range from -9223372036854775808 to +9223372036854775807 and called `bigint` i.e. large-range integer.
3. Run `rake db:migrate` to migrate your database.
4. Restart your server by running `rails server` and you are up and running.

For more information on Numeric Type, see https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/datatype-numeric.html

Answer (score 17):

Good day.
By default column create with length = 32 bytes

To change this, you can create a migration, for example:

```
t.integer :some_field, :limit => 8
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there any way to change the integer limit without using migrations?

Comment: Can you tell the situation in more detail? Migration - standart way for patternt ORM ... if you have some issue - please describe

Comment: @Sergey
change_column [:table_name], [:column_name], :integer, limit: 20

Comment: @Sergey You could do some custom SQL `ALTER ...` but it's much more maintainable, consistent, explicit, simplet, etc to do it with migrations: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html

Answer (score 10):

I stumbled upon this problem today with PostgreSQL too. I know the question is old and the author was using SQLite but since a lot of people seem to end up here like I did let me post an updated solution.

For **Rails 5.1** (I believe for 4.1 and above but didn't test) and **PostgreSQL** (probably with other databases too) the correct way is to set the column type to `bigint`, using the `limit: 8` option doesn't affect the database.

This is the example code using a table named products and a column named quantity:

```
class ChangeProductsQuantityToBigint < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    change_column :products, :quantity, :bigint
  end
end
```

Comment: This will fix the limit in the database, but Rails won't use it. I think this is because Rails doesn't know what a Postgres bigint is. So Rail's integer validation will still fail. So even if the database can accept larger ints, Rails won't.

Comment: This works great with the latest versions of rails. Limit no longer works and bigint is indeed the correct way.

Comment: Works good in Rails 7.