# Primary key and foreign key out of range

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, foreign-keys, rails-activerecord

I have a person model:

```
id: int, uuid:bigint
```

and a blogpost:

```
id: int, uuid:bigint, person_id: int
```

I want `blogpost.person` to return the person model's uuid, not their id.

I tried (person class):

```
has_many :blogposts, dependent: :delete_all, inverse_of: :deck, primary_key: :uuid
```

But then I get:

```
ActiveModel::RangeError: 1534420711008 is out of range for ActiveModel::Type::Integer with limit 4 bytes.
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting error indicating number is "out of range for ActiveRecord::Type::Integer with limit 4" when attempting to save large(ish) integer value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29538530/getting-error-indicating-number-is-out-of-range-for-activerecordtypeinteger)

Comment: Not even a little bit

Answer (score 1):

You've defined the foreign key `person_id`  as an `int`, but you're trying to get it to store the `bigint` uuid for the association in an `int` field. Try using bigint for `person_id` in your schema instead.

This is assuming you've set `uuid` as the primary key for `Person`. If you haven't: https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html#overriding-the-naming-conventions

**Edit**

As you stated, you don't want to make `uuid` the primary key for person. Foreign keys generally reference primary keys in another table, but can also reference unique indexed columns.

First, `blogpost.person` should not return a `uuid` but rather a `Person` object, by convention. So, the easy way would be to add a scope or method:

```
class Blogpost < ApplicationModel

  def person
    Person.find_by_uuid(person_uuid)
  end

end
```

Second, if the `blogpost.person_id` field is holding a `uuid`, it should (1) be a `bigint`, not an `int`, and (2) be renamed `person_uuid` for your sanity, as in the example above. If that's all the logic you need, that solution should work fine (given that `uuid` column is a unique index in Person). You can also define this as a proper foreign key relationship:

```
class Blogpost < ApplicationModel
  belongs_to :person, foreign_key: :person_uuid
end

class Person < ApplicationModel
  has_many :blogposts, foreign_key: :person_uuid, inverse_of: :person, primary_key: :uuid
end
```

However, make sure to define `person_uuid` and `uuid` as unique indexes in your migrations, if they're not primary keys. (`unique: true` in column definition)

Comment: Thank you for the effort, but I don't want the primary key of person to be its uuid. I'd much rather have the person_id field on a blog object simply reference the uuid field on a person. Is that not possible?